# How can I use an empty href attribute without redirect?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to have `href` without being redirect back to the root in angular2? As I have this `<a href="" (click)="modal.open()"></a>` code to open up a modal but its redirecting me back to my home page.

I know its because of the routeConfig angular has, but is there a way to say bypass that?

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Note sure if removing href completely is valid, it may be without check w3c validation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use:

`<a href="javascript:;"">Link</a>`

or maybe better if you don't want to use inline JavaScript:

`<a href="" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Link</a>`

to realize a Link without any side-effect.

Comment: is this meant for production?

Comment: it is not, it can be blocked by chrome. check the answer by an-angular-dev

Answer (score 9):

`href="javascript:;"` will produce an error after clicking link when `Content-Security-Policy` disallows inline scripts (`script-src: 'self';` for example) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).

You can use empty href with event.preventDefault() on click instead.

```html
<a href="" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a better answer to this question could be:

```
<a href="" (click)='$event.preventDefault();modal.open()'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular uses `ng-href` instead of `href`. So if you want to have href attr, then you should use `ng-href`.

If you want to have valid HTML according to W3C specs, then do not use Angular because the `(click)=...` etc are not valid attributtes :) IMHO this HTML validity is overrated.

If all you want to do is to open a modal window, then do not use `<a>` tag, because that's not what they are primary for. The `<a>` is for navigation. Use `<button>` instead. That will also solve your problem with href.